# How to get user info after verifying a receipt with the App Store?

Tags: app-store, in-app-purchase

I want to track the purchases at the server side after verifying a receipt.

But the [receipt from apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/VerifyingStoreReceipts/VerifyingStoreReceipts.html) gives all the info except user's.

So what's the safe way to obtain user's data which has not been tampered with?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add third party tool for it. apple doesn't allow users information.

Comment: hi @MonishBansal could you tell me any third party tool which does this.